# Jquery DataTables 1.10 ajax datasource issue - table UI doesn't get refreshed with new data

Tags: datatables, ajax-datasource, datatable-pagination

Sample application:
https://simple-json-service.azurewebsites.net/

**Issue:**
Initial load works fine, but when I click page-2, or "next", the ajax action happens, but the table UI is stuck.

Trying to get a datatable to paginate over ajax - the ajax request & response happen correctly, but the UI doesn't refresh/reload.

**HTML:**

```
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                pageLength: 3,
                pagingType: 'full_numbers',
                ajax: {
                    url: "/home/data_post", 
                    type: "Post",
                    dataSrc: function (data) {
                        return data.data
                    },
                    
                },
                columns: [
                    { "data": "Id" },
                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Email" }
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>
}
<main>
    <table id="example" class="display" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</main>
```

**MVC Action/API**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Data_post()
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>();
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "1", Name = "John Doe", Email = "john.doe.1@example.com" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "2", Name = "Jane Doe", Email = "jane.doe.2@example.com" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "3", Name = "Joe Bloggs", Email = "joe.bloggs.3@example.com" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "4", Name = "Jane Bloggs", Email = "jane.bloggs.4@example.com" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "5", Name = "John Smith", Email = "john.smith.5@example.com" });
            customers.Add(new Customer { Id = "6", Name = "Jane Smith", Email = "jane.smith.6@example.com" });

            var _start = HttpContext.Request.Form["start"];
            var _length = Request.Form["length"];

            int.TryParse(_start, out int start);
            int.TryParse(_length, out int length);


            if (length == 0)
                length = 3;

            var originalCount = customers.Count;
            var filteredCount = originalCount;

            var filteredData = customers.Skip(start).Take(length).ToList();

            var dataToReturn = new
            {
                draw = length,
                recordsTotal = originalCount,
                recordsFiltered = filteredCount,
                data = filteredData
            };


            return Json(dataToReturn);
        }
```